# Set name/label for custom links in TYPO3 RTE

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I added a new link class to the TYPO3 (6.2.14) RTE like shown below

```
RTE {
    classesAnchor {
        myNewClass {
            class = very-long-class additional-class
            type = page
        }
    }
    default {
        proc.allowedClasses := addToList(very-long-class additional-class)
        buttons {
            link.properties.class.allowedClasses := addToList(very-long-class additional-class)
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works fine and the editor can choose the new link style when he selects some text in the RTE and creates a link (shown below).

[image]

My problem is, that the link name is not really understandable. Is it possible to define a name or label for the link (changing the class-name is not an option), so the "Style" field will show a more understandable name?

Answer (score 1):

The names are set in "classes" of the RTE object. The value are any CSS-styles to give a hint, how it looks like.

```
RTE.classes {
    your-class-name {
        name = Your Awesome Class Name
        value = margin: 2px; padding: 2px; background: #00b5dc; color: #fff; border: 1px solid #3a6674;
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW. I guess it is not possible, to set two classes at the same time.

Comment: Thanks, but RTE.classes does'nt seem to respect the "type" attribute, so the new class is visible/selectable for all type of links. It seems, RTE does not support adding "name" values to "classesAnchor" classes